# How to get scroll behavior to work with this setup in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, scrolltop

I have tried various iterations of scrollBehavior and haven't been able to get it working with this setup. I have tried adding it to all routes, I have tried adding meta data to each route and doing it that way. Nothing seems to work and the Vue app won't scroll to top. Here is where I am at:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'
import MusicView from '../views/MusicView.vue'
import GenreView from '../views/GenreView.vue'
import AboutView from '../views/AboutView.vue'
import MusicFiltersView from '../views/MusicFiltersView.vue'

const router = createRouter({

history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),

scrollBehavior(to){
const scroll = {}
if (to.meta.toTop) scroll.top = 0
if (to.meta.smoothScroll) scroll.behavior = 'smooth'
return scroll
},

routes: 

[
{
  path: '/',
  component: HomeView,
  meta: {toTop: true, smoothScroll: true}
},
{
  path: '/music',
  component: MusicView,
  meta: {toTop: true, smoothScroll: true}
},
{
  path: '/about',
  component: AboutView,
  meta: {toTop: true, smoothScroll: true}
},
{
  path: '/genres',
  component: GenreView,
  meta: {toTop: true, smoothScroll: true}
},
{
  path: '/music-filters',
  component: MusicFiltersView,
  meta: {toTop: true, smoothScroll: true}
},
],

 })

 export default router
```

This is using Vue 3.

Comment: a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.  With just your router code, I am not able to reproduce. See this [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-5nu9je?file=src%2Fviews%2Fhome.vue,src%2Fviews%2Ftest.vue,src%2Frouter%2Findex.js). Given some scrollable components to navigate between, the smooth scroll to top behavior is working ok.

Comment: Hi @yoduh, I've realised it is because I have the RouterView inside a div in the app (with a fixed sidebar and search bar), when I open a new page view the router doesn't get to the RouterView. When I took it out of the div it worked. I need it in the div for it to fit with the rest of the app. Is there a way to target the RouterView inside a div? I'm guessing by Id?

Comment: Got it. Used to this to get the div to scroll to top on every page.

`const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
  scrollBehavior() {
    document.getElementById("RouterView").scrollTop = 0;
  },
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, this was the answer:

```
const router = createRouter({   history: createWebHashHistory(),   routes,   scrollBehavior() {     document.getElementById("RouterView").scrollTop = 0;   }, });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).